# Find indices in each column of a 2d array for every element in a 1d array without looping

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to do a Monte Carlo simulation of a contest and allocate points based on standings for each iteration of the sim. I currently have a working solution using Numpy's argwhere, however for large contest sizes and simulations (e.g. 25000 contestants and 10000 simulations) the script is extremely slow due to list comprehensions.

```
import numpy as np 

#sample arrays, the actual sizes are arbitrary based on the number of contestants (ranks.shape[1]) and simulations (ranks.shape[0]) but len(field) is always equal to number of contestants and len(payout_array)

#points to be allocated based on finish position
points_array = np.array([100,50,0,0,0])

#standings for the first simulation = [2,4,3,1,0], the second = [4,0,1,2,3]
ranks = np.array([[2, 4, 4, 1],
 [4, 0, 0, 4],
 [3, 1, 1, 0],
 [1, 2, 3, 2],
 [0, 3, 2, 3]])

field = np.arange(5)

ind = [np.argwhere(ranks==i) for i in field]
roi = [np.sum(points_array[i[:,0]]) for i in ind]
print(roi)
```

returns: [100, 100, 100, 0, 300]

This solution works and is very fast for small arrays:

```
%timeit [np.argwhere(ranks==i) for i in field]
36.2 µs ± 1.08 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

However for large contestant fields and many simulations the script hangs on the list comprehension using argwhere (still running after 20 minutes for a 30k person field and 10k simulations with no memory constraints on my machine). Is there a way to vectorize argwhere or reduce the complexity of the lookup to help speed up finding the indices in ranks for all of the elements in field?

Comment: Do the numbers in `ranks` represent the bib numbers of the contestants?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny This appears not to give the same result. That being said, an explanation would be a very good idea indeed (as well as possible input constraints, like is `np.all(np.sort(ranks, axis=0).T == np.arange(ranks.shape[0]))` always true?).

Comment: @RoySmart's answer worked. in this case the ranks array was generated from `np.argsort(x, axis=0)[::-1]` where x was an array of actual points scored (or finish times in the case of a race with bib numbers) by each contestant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) to vectorize this behavior. This works because your final array is in order of the contestants, and you need to find the index of their finish position based on the `rank` array.

```py
import numpy as np

#sample arrays, the actual sizes are arbitrary based on the number of contestants (ranks.shape[1]) and simulations (ranks.shape[0]) but len(field) is always equal to number of contestants and len(payout_array)

#points to be allocated based on finish position
points_array = np.array([100,50,0,0,0])

#standings for the first simulation = [2,4,3,1,0], the second = [4,0,1,2,3]
ranks = np.array([[2, 4, 4, 1],
 [4, 0, 0, 4],
 [3, 1, 1, 0],
 [1, 2, 3, 2],
 [0, 3, 2, 3]])

roi = points_array[np.argsort(ranks, axis=0)].sum(axis=1)
print(roi)
```

Comment: Good solution. Since the above assumption seems true, the sort can certainly be replaced by a memory indirection. This alternative method runs in `O(n)`  rather than `O(n log n)` for the `argsort` so it should be significantly faster for large inputs.

Comment: @JérômeRichard, I see what you mean, do you think a radix sort would accomplish what you're talking about? I see that the documentation for [`numpy.sort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) says that it uses radix sort under the hood, but the documentation for `numpy.argsort` only talks about timsort.

Comment: A sort is not needed here since the N numbers are integers between 0 and N-1 included and we already know the sorted result. We just need the locations and we can have this with something similar to `idx[ranks] = np.arange(N)` for a matrix.